# How to add converters when ApplicationConversionService.getSharedInstance() is no longer modifiable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm in the process of upgrading spring boot from 2.4.2 to 2.5.6.
In our code we have been using `ApplicationConversionService.getSharedInstance().addConverter()` to add our custom converters. It puzzles me a bit that this is mentioned as a "New feature" rather than a breaking change for Spring boot 2.5.0-RC1, see the top mention here. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases?page=3
It was changed by this PR: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26088

How can we add the converters instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the converter as a bean and annotate the bean definition with `@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding`. The simplest way to do so is probably to annotate the converter class with `@Component` and `@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding`.

See also this part of the reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.conversion